# Need to merge two or more datatable vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have 5 different DataTables. 
Each DataTable has always the same amount of rows with one repeated column called EmployeeID, which is primary key. Now I need to combine all columns from all tables along with data into one DataTable
All DataTable are part of the same DataSet called Employee

```
DT1
EmployeeID, Name   , Age , Phone
1,          Mr. A  , 45  , 123456789

DT2
EmployeeID, Address      , Rank        , Title
1,          Main Street  , Top Level   , Manager

Expected output. 
The DTAll table will have the following columns with data
EmployeeID, Name   , Age,  phone     , Address     , Rank      , Title
1           Mr. A  , 45 ,  123456789 , Main Street , Top Level , Manager
```

Comment: Your question is the answer.... Look into `DataTable.Merge()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I would suggest you look into the `DataTable.Marge()` method - like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge(v=vs.110).aspx).

It would look like something along the following code:

```
    DT1.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {DT1.Columns("EmployeeID")}
    DT2.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {DT2.Columns("EmployeeID")}

    DT1.Merge(DT2)
```

Hope I understood correctly and that that helped!

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I tried to use Merge before, but I did not know I could define primary key which allow me to merge two or more table which are vertically partitioned.

Comment: Glad it did the trick, @Shai. Since you're new, just remember to mark the answer as your solution so others know the question was solved.